# In C++11 is there a way to not require template arguments when calling a function that takes any callable as an argument, including bound methods?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

In order to broaden my understanding of C++11, I'm experimenting with writing functional helpers and seeing if I can make calling them less verbose. Consider the following code:

```
#include <list>

int timesTwo(int x) { return x*2; }
int timesX(int x, int y) { return x*y; }

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : value(a) {};
    int fooTimesTwo() const { return value*2; };
    int value;
};

template <class T, class U>
std::list<U> myMap(const std::list<T> &list, const std::function<U(const T &)> &func)
{
    std::list<U> result;

    for(typename std::list<T>::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        result.push_back(func(*it));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::list<int> numbers2 = myMap<int,int>(numbers, [] (int x) { return x*2; });
    std::list<int> numbers3 = myMap<int,int>(numbers, &timesTwo);
    std::list<int> numbers4 = myMap<int,int>(numbers, std::bind(timesX, 2, std::placeholders::_1));

    std::list<Foo> fooList = {Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)};
    std::list<int> numbers5 = myMap<Foo,int>(fooList, &Foo::fooTimesTwo);    
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway to rewrite `myMap` so that

1. all four of the calls to it in my code example do not require any template arguments, and...
2. there's only one general implementation, and I don't have to manually write an overloaded version for each combination of types I want to call it with?

I've tried changing the second argument of `myMap` to be a third templated type instead of `std::function`, but it fails because a) the second templated type `U` can't be inferred, and b) even if it could, the fourth call to `myMap` will cause an error on line 20 due to `&Foo::fooTimesTwo` not being a function or function pointer.

I'm willing to consider all of the various features of C++11 to do this, and I don't particularly care if it makes the declaration or definition of `myMap` obtuse or unreadable. I'm just wondering if it's possible and, if so, what sort of techniques and C++11 features can accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt to implement [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) in C++11, but I think it would be really cumbersome.

It's fairly simple to make a function template for a generalized callable:

```
template <class T, class F>
auto myMap(const std::list<T> &list, F&& func)
    -> std::list<typename std::decay<decltype(func(*list.begin()))>::type>
{
    using U = typename std::decay<decltype(func(*list.begin()))>::type;
    std::list<U> result;

    for(typename std::list<T>::const_iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        result.push_back(func(*it));
    }

    return result;
}
```

You get expression sfinae for free. Now there's only member function pointer to be taken care of:

```
template <class T, class F>
auto myMap(const std::list<T> &list, F&& func)
    -> std::list<typename std::decay<decltype(((*list.begin()).*func)())>::type>
{
    return myMap(list, [=](T const& t){ return (t.*func)(); });
}
```

Now you can call your functions as expected. [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ARezLfXK4AYRjYC6)

---

While at it, you could replace this ugly `for` loop with a ranged for:

```
for(auto const& elem : list) {
    results.push_back(func(elem));
}
```

Or use an algorithm:

```
std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), std::back_inserter(result), func);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! In studying your answer, I have learned quite a bit about auto, decltype and decay.